# Combine ManualResetEvent and token.WaitHandle.WaitOne

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

I got:

```
internal void Start(CancellationToken token)
{
   while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
       //do work
       token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(67));
   }       
}
```

So i start this method in new `Task` and do some work in loop untill i need to cancel it with `token`
Some times i need to force new loop iteration, without waiting this 67 seconds.
I think i need something like:

```
public ManualResetEvent ForceLoopIteration { get; set; }
```

Meanwhile i cant understand how to use it with token.
Maybe something like `WaitHandle.WaitAny()`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Youre on the right way, try this:

```
WaitHandle.WaitAny(
    new[] { token.WaitHandle, ForceLoopIteration },
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(67));
```

This waits for the occurence of one of the following

- cancelation is requested on `token`
- `ForceLoopIteration` is set
- timeout of 67 seconds has been elapsed